# PHP Version Incorrect Using IIS

Tags: php

I have a newly installed version of PHP on my Windows 7 machine using IIS. I downloaded version 5.6.17, and followed the installation instructions. However, when I do `phpinfo()`, it returns version 5.3.28.

This is the first time installing PHP, so I am not upgrading. Everything works with PHP, however the version is incorrect. I have some functions I want to use that are not supported by 5.3. I am thinking I missed a step in the installation, but haven't been able to figure this one out. Anyone know what that might be?

Comment: What happens when you run `php -v` from a command line?